# How to understand when new application downloaded?

Tags: android

I want to learn how can I get information about when a new application installed? Is there a specific permission in AndroidManifest.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if I understand you right, but have a look at a broadcastreceiver listening to:
ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED; ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED; ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE; ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html